# JQuery Mobile Dynamic Div Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to JQuery + JQuery mobile.

I am attempting to create dynamic div elements for styling purposes. I am pulling in JSON from an AJAX call, tossing it into an unordered list, and wrapping it into a div. The AJAX + JSON works beautifully, but when I go to create the DIV within the script and attach it into another div container, it doesn't work. I've done a lot of reading on this, but none of the solutions I've found seems to work for the div part.

I've simplified my code down to the following:

HTML:

```
  <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div id="someDiv" data-role="content"></div>
        <div id="anotherDiv"></div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newDiv = '<div id="d1"><p>This will attach to the content</p></div>';
    var aDiv = '<div id="test" data-role="page"><p>This never gets displayed because of data-role?</p></div>';
    $("#someDiv").html(newDiv).trigger('create');
    $("#anotherDiv").html(aDiv).trigger('create');
});​
```

Note how `aDiv` doesn't attach to `anotherDiv`. I suspect this has something to do with the `data-role="page"` attribute in `aDiv`.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dAX9f/)

I've been stuck on this for 1+ day. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: It appears to work to me.  What exactly are you trying to have happen that is not happening?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: Note how `newDiv` attaches to a div, but `aDiv` does not attach to a div because of the `data-role="page"`. I cant figure out why `aDiv` won't attach to div id `anotherDiv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact your `aDiv` is being attached, just not displayed (you can examine your markup in Firebug/WebInspector/DragonFly and see this) since only one JQM page at a time is displayed.

If you want to attach a new page you can try adding it to your `body`

Here's a fork of your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/49LgB/

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now that the `page` actually points to another area that is hidden until linked to. I can't believe I've been banging my head over this all day. Thanks!!!